# Corona how to insert a row at an index

Tags: lua, coronasdk, mobile-application

Based on which was row is clicked in a table view I want to insert a row underneath of that.

But I can only get it to insert at the bottom of the table view

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are hoping to get any help here you need to provide far more information than this. You need to show the relevant bits of code you have and what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so, that i would make each row as an object, having a value (row number), then adding a listener to each row object that creates a new row object underneath itself (number * row heights) and a loop that will increase the y coordinate on each row (self.y = self.y + row height) that has a value bigger than the one was clicked (and also increase the value by 1 then)

Hope you get some ideas from it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to delete all items from the tableView and reinsert them with your new entry.